# How to inject members in a base Application class of a library?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-library

I have the following situation:

An app module, with the application class

```
public class MainApplication extends CoreApplication implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this);
        logger.log();
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

And CoreApplication is defined in another library module

```
public class CoreApplication extends Application {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        logger.log();
    }
}
```

Here the AppComponent.java:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AndroidInjectionModule.class, 
ApplicationModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Logger is a provided in the app module in the following class

```
@Module(includes = CoreModule.class)
public abstract class ApplicationModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    static Logger provideLog() {
        return new Logger();
    }
}
```

CoreModule.java instead is defined in the library module:

```
@Module
public abstract class CoreModule {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "logTag";

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract DetailActivity contributeActivityInjector();
}
```

The problem is that I cannot inject Logger in CoreApplication (I get a NPE), but I can in the MainApplication.

I can inject it without issues also in the activities of the core library like this:

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);

        logger.log();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are injected when you call `inject(this)`.

That's why you get a NPE when you call `super.oncreate()` (and subsequently, `logger.log()`) before `inject()`.

Move `super.onCreate()` after the `inject()` call or better yet, move the injection code to your base App class (CoreApplication).

```
public abstract class CoreApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        inject();
        logger.log();
    }

    private void inject() {
        DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}

public class MainApplication extends CoreApplication {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        logger.log();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Igor moving super.onCreate() worked. The second option I believe it's not applicable in my case because the App module extends  the CoreModule and DaggerAppComponent is not even visible in the core library (where the base application is located)